# How do I push multiple objects to an array without overwriting the array with the most recent object that was pushed

Tags: html, angularjs

The problem i'm having is that whenever I click submit, the object gets pushed to the array. When I click submit to add another ingredient to the array it pushes another object to the array but also copies it's information into all previous objects in the array.

html

```
<form ng-submit="addToIngredients(newIngredient)">
        <input ng-model="newIngredient.quantity" placeholder="e.g. 1/3" type="text">
        <select ng-model="newIngredient.unit">
          <option value="ml">ml</option>
          <option value="l">l</option>
          <option value="tsp">tsp</option>
          <option value="tbsp">tbsp</option>
          <option value="floz">floz</option>
          <option value="cup">cup</option>
          <option value="pnt">pnt</option>
          <option value="qt">qt</option>
          <option value="gal">gal</option>
          <option value="qty">qty</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-options="stockItem.name for stockItem in stockItems track by stockItem._id"
                ng-model="newIngredient.item">
        </select>
        <button type='submit'>Add to ingredients</button>
      </form>
```

function on controller

```
$scope.ingredients = [];
$scope.addToIngredients = function(newIngredient){
    $scope.ingredients.push(newIngredient);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably javascript inheritance.

You could try:

```
$scope.ingredients.push(angular.copy(newIngredient));
```

It is a hack...

Comment: This didn't work. The information in the first object of the array is replaced with the second. So I essentially have 2 copies of the second object in my array  now. Thanks though

Comment: what does function(newIngredient){ console.log(newIngrediant output?}

Comment: the output of console.log(newIngredient) is the correct information but when that object gets pushed to the array it copies over all the other objects in the array.

Comment: Sorry user3791775 you're solution actually worked. (I didn't have gulp running when I was making the changes). Thanks for the help but if you can think of a cleaner way please let me know.

Comment: maybe it works now with gulp running (without the hack)